# T-SQL -- Why do ALTER and UPDATE statement only run when separated into their own batch?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms, update, alter-table

I have update and alter statements that are only running when they are put into they're own batch. Below is my shortened version. It'd probably be a good idea to skip the code and read my question below.

```
DROP TABLE #tmpImportData
USE database_name
GO

DECLARE @localVar VARCHAR(MAX) = 'data'
DECLARE @localVar VARCHAR(MAX) = 'data'
DECLARE @localVar VARCHAR(MAX) = 'data'
DECLARE @localVar int = 1
--Etc...

DECLARE @localVar INT
DECLARE @localVarVARCHAR(50)    
DECLARE @localVar AS BINARY (16)    
---Etc...


CREATE TABLE #tmpImportData (GuideFirstName VARCHAR(MAX), GuideLastName VARCHAR(MAX), 
                             email VARCHAR(MAX), group_id_text VARCHAR(MAX), CandidateName VARCHAR(MAX), 
                             grade_text VARCHAR(5), dateofbirth DATETIME

                             )

SET @sql = 'BULK INSERT #tmpImportData FROM '''+@fileName+''' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR ='';'', ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'', FIRSTROW = 1)'
EXEC (@sql)

--John O. How many rows from the import
SELECT @countCandidateImport = count(*) FROM #tmpImportData

--Fix some import data before any proccessing. We need to remove any punctuation, extra spaces, etc.
UPDATE #tmpImportData SET CandidateName = LTRIM(RTRIM(CandidateName)) FROM #tmpImportData
UPDATE #tmpImportData SET CandidateName = Replace(CandidateName,'.', '') FROM #tmpImportData
--UPDATE #tmpImportData SET CandidateName = Replace(CandidateName,',', '') FROM #tmpImportData

--Check DB for current district. If not exists create new one
SELECT @districtId = id, @ditrict_admins_restricted = CountAdminPermited, @candidates_restricted = count_candidate_restricted
FROM DistrictsTable WHERE name = RTRIM(LTRIM(@districtName))


--John O. What is whytry?
IF @districtId IS NULL
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO districtstable (name, active, CountAdminPermited, why_try_permitted) VALUES (RTRIM(LTRIM(@districtName)), 1, 3, @iswhyTry)
    SELECT @districtId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
ELSE BEGIN
    SELECT @count_created_district_admins = count(*) 
    FROM GuidesTable gt
    INNER JOIN guides_to_permission gtp ON gtp.guide_id = gt.ID
    WHERE gt.DistrictID = @districtId AND gtp.permission_id = 0 AND gt.Active = 1

    IF(@count_created_district_admins >= @ditrict_admins_restricted)
    BEGIN
        SET @messageID = 1
    END

    SELECT @count_created_candidates = count(*)
    FROM CandidatesTable ct
    WHERE ct.DistrictID =  @districtId AND ct.Active = 1
    IF @count_created_candidates + @countCandidateImport >= @candidates_restricted
    BEGIN
        SET @messageID = 2  
    END

    IF(@messageID <> -1)
        RETURN
END
select 1
--Create School
DECLARE @schoolId AS INT
SET @schoolId = NULL
SELECT @schoolId = SchoolsTable.ID FROM SchoolsTable WHERE SchoolsTable.Name = LTRIM(RTRIM(@schoolName))
IF @schoolId IS NULL
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO schoolstable (districtid, name, Active) VALUES (@districtId, @schoolName, 1)
        SELECT @schoolId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    END
ELSE 

SET @adminGuideId = NULL
SELECT @adminGuideId = GuidesTable.ID FROM GuidesTable WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(FirstName)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(@FirstName)) 
    AND LTRIM(RTRIM(LastName)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(@LastName)) AND LTRIM(RTRIM(EmailAddress)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(@adminLogin))
select @adminGuideId
IF @adminGuideId IS NULL 
BEGIN
        SET @password = HASHBYTES('MD5', @passwordAdmin)                

        INSERT INTO GuidesTable (DistrictID, ClassID, FirstName         , LastName          , EmailAddress, [Password], createddate, Administrator, Active, website_access_level_id)
        VALUES                  (@districtId, 0     , @FirstName        , @LastName         , @adminLogin , @password , GetDate()  , 1            , 1     , 1)
        SET @tmpGuideId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
        INSERT INTO guides_to_permission (guides_to_permission.guide_id ,guides_to_permission.permission_id) 
        VALUES                           (@tmpGuideId                   ,0                 )
        INSERT INTO guides_to_school_access (guides_to_school_access.guide_id , guides_to_school_access.school_id) 
        VALUES                              (@tmpGuideId                      , @schoolId                        )
END
ELSE BEGIN
        SELECT @AccessToSchoolId = gtsa.id FROM guides_to_school_access gtsa WHERE @adminGuideId = gtsa.guide_id AND @schoolId = gtsa.school_id
        IF @AccessToSchoolId IS NULL
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO guides_to_school_access (guides_to_school_access.guide_id , guides_to_school_access.school_id) 
            VALUES                              (@adminGuideId                    , @schoolId                        )
        END
END
GO
--Create unique guides
--declare @SQL1 nvarchar(max)
--set @SQL1 = '
ALTER TABLE #tmpImportData ADD group_id INT
ALTER TABLE #tmpImportData ADD guide_id INT
ALTER TABLE #tmpImportData ADD password_plain_text VARCHAR(500)
ALTER TABLE #tmpImportData ADD guide_email VARCHAR(500)
ALTER TABLE #tmpImportData ADD class_id INT 

--exec sp_executesql @SQL1      
GO

UPDATE #tmpImportData SET group_id = CAST(group_id_text AS INT)
UPDATE #tmpImportData SET group_id = 0 WHERE group_id IS NULL

SELECT * FROM #tmpImportData
GO
```

So the table updates and alters fine with the code above. But if I remove the two `GO` statements before the last one, and just leave the last one after the select. The table isn't updated or altered. Any idea why this is happening?

ALSO, IF I run this with NO `GO` statements everything is executed except the alter and the update and the select.

Comment: Just a brief side note: `GO` is **not** a (SQL) statement - it's a **separator** that is specific to SQL Server Mgmt Studio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that there's a database error that you're not seeing here.

If you remove the `GO` statement right before the two final `UPDATE` statements, I'd imagine that the query crashes with something like "unknown column 'group_id'".

This happens because an execution plan is generated for each *batch* at a time, i.e. every time you pass `GO`. In my experience, this plan does not always consider statements that make schema changes (except `SELECT .. INTO` operations and index operations). If you try to generate a query plan that includes the `group_id` column before the `ALTER TABLE` statements have actually been executed, that column won't actually exist yet.

My best advice may not work for every conceivable scenario, but it will for yours: create the temp table correctly from the start, in this case by including the columns that you're `ADD`ing in the original `CREATE TABLE` statement at the top, so you won't have to `ALTER` it later on in the code.

Answer (score 3):

[GO (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx)

> Signals the end of a batch of Transact-SQL statements to the SQL
>   Server utilities.

[RETURN (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx)

> Exits unconditionally from a query or procedure. RETURN is immediate
>   and complete and can be used at any point to exit from a procedure,
>   batch, or statement block. Statements that follow RETURN are not
>   executed.

When you remove to `GO` your entire block of code is one batch. The `RETURN` you have terminates the batch and nothing more will be executed. When you have the `GO` in the code, execution will continue with the next batch when you do `RETURN`.